# Wrong username and displayname after user registraton WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When people are buying a product through the WooCommerce extension, I have enabled that they can create an account on checkout. I don't let them choose their own username and password.

Now I see that WP uses some part of the emailaddress to create a username, and the display name is based on the first name filled in on checkout.

Now I want to change that:

- username must be the complete emailaddress [SOLVED];
- display name must be the first name + last name [UNSOLVED].

I tried this: for display name with my 'no knowledge' of PHP:

```
add_filter('pre_user_display_name', 'wsis_pre_user_display_name');
function wsis_pre_user_display_name($display_name) {
    $first = get_user_field("billing_first_name"); 
    $last = get_user_field("billing_last_name"); 
    $display_name = $first . $last;

    return $display_name;
}
```

This filter is mentioned in their codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user. But no examples and my code didn't work. Anybody can help?

In user.php wp-includes folder I found the filter, now get it working :-).

```
/**
     * Filter a user's display name before the user is created or updated.
     *
     * @since 2.0.3
     *
     * @param string $display_name The user's display name.
     */
    $display_name = apply_filters( 'pre_user_display_name', $display_name );

    if ( empty($description) )
        $description = '';
```

Second try did something! It left the display name completely empty:

```
add_filter('pre_user_display_name', 'pre_user_display_name');
function pre_user_display_name($display_name) {
    $first = get_the_author_meta('first_name'); 
    $last = get_the_author_meta('last_name'); 

    $display_name = $first . $last;

    return $display_name;
}
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the username as complete email address, you can add following code in functions.php file of your theme.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_new_customer_data','change_username');

function change_username($user_data)
        {
           return array(
                      'user_login' => $user_data['user_email'],
                      'user_pass'  => $user_data['user_pass'],
                      'user_email' => $user_data['user_email'],
                      'role'       => 'customer'

                   );
        }
```

Comment: You are awesome. About the display name, I have added the source where this filter is mentioned, can you help me with that one as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to set the display name to first name + last name.

```
// Sets the display name to first name and last name
add_filter( 'pre_user_display_name' , 'default_display_name' );
function default_display_name($name) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $firstname = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] );
    }
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $lastname = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] );
    }
    $name = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
    return $name;
}
```

Source : http://geektamin.com/blog/533/why-update_user_meta-display_name-doesnt-work-and-how-to-use-pre_user_display_name-instead/

Comment: Here's a more powerful version of this code: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/16015#issuecomment-338519085